# Dimension mismatch in keras

Tags: python, keras

I was trying to run a 10 fold cross validation on my dataset.I had reshaped my data before training as follows

```
data = data.reshape(500,1,1028,1)
data_y = np_utils.to_categorical(data_y, 3)
```

After this i described my model

```
   for train,test in kf.split(data):
    fold+=1
    print("Fold #{}".format(fold))
    x_train = data[train]
    y_train = data_y[train]
    x_test = data[test]
    y_test = data_y[test]
    print(x_train.shape)
    model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3),input_shape=(1,1028,1)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    #model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(34, (1, 4)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))

    model.add(Conv2D(64,(1, 3)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    #model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64, (1, 4)))
    model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))

    model.add(Flatten())

    #fully connected for new model

    model.add(Dense(550))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(250))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(100))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(25))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
    model.add(Dropout(0.25))
    model.add(Dense(3))
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=Adam(), metrics=['accuracy'])

    model.fit(x_train.reshape(450,1,1028,1), y_train,
          batch_size=5,
          epochs=1,
          verbose=1,
          validation_data=(x_test, y_test))
    pred = model.predict(x_test)

    oos_y.append(y_test)
    pred = np.argmax(pred, axis=1)  # raw probabilities to chosen class (highest probability)
    oos_pred.append(pred)

    # Measure this fold's accuracy
    y_compare = np.argmax(y_test, axis=1)  # For accuracy calculation
    score = metrics.accuracy_score(y_compare, pred)
    print("Fold score (accuracy): {}".format(score))
```

The problem is that when I run my code the code runs properly for fold 1 but for fold 2 it gives me the following error

```
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer conv2d_5: expected ndim=4, found ndim=2
```

When I checked the dimensions of x_train it was `(450, 1, 1028, 1)`

I am not sure what the error is.

Comment: It is not easy to infer from this code only. can you post the code for whole model architecture?

Comment: and also why adding layers inside loop?

Comment: I have updated the model code.
@Mitiku what would be an efficient way to add layers?

Comment: This code still missing some layers. I can see only four con2d layers, and from error message it is clear that there are at least five con2d layers.

Comment: "...would be an efficient way..." it depends on what you are trying to achieve. Why are you iterating over train and test data?

Comment: I do not have 5th convolutional layer.I have copied the entire model here.

Comment: You define your model outside the for loop. Then with every iteration you add the whole model again. `conv2d_5` is the first conv2d layer of the second iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot.That worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding model layers inside loop over and over. The error was produced when you try to add convolutional layer(for second iteration of loop) after softmax activation layer(the last layer for first iteration of the loop). After careful inspection I've come to the following solution to your question.

First split the dataset into train and test

```
for train_index, test_index in kf.split(data):
    X_train, X_test = data[train_index], data[test_index]
    y_train, y_test = data_y[train_index], data_y[test_index]
```

then add layers to model outside of the loop.

```
model.add(Conv2D(32, (1, 3),input_shape=(1,1028,1)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
#model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))
model.add(Conv2D(34, (1, 4)))
model.add(BatchNormalization(axis=-1))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,2)))
# ... The reset of the code
```